# git client and browser separation on https server

Tags: git, ssl, curl, https, pinning

I'm trying to enable certificate pinning for `git clone`. In order to do that I've used `openssl s_client` and grabbed the certificate from server hello:

```
openssl s_client -connect anongit.gentoo.org:443 2>&1 </dev/null
```

But the following command is actually failed on the server certificate check:

```
git clone -c http.sslVerify=yes -c 'http.pinnedpubkey=sha256//13fY3xnMhZp6C5wKICfMZVJbN+AtmBbTXSy+sjJvKDE=' https://anongit.gentoo.org/git/repo/gentoo.git
```

Doing a little investigation I've discovered in network dumps that certificates differ for `openssl s_client` and `git clone`. Only differences (in client hello) that I can see in the dumps are: SNI for `anongit.gentoo.org` and ALPN for `http/1.1` in `git` traffic. It seems too little to distinguish git client and browser.

So, the question is: how extactly the server detects a `git` client in order to reply with a different certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the difference-maker here is SNI:

```
openssl s_client -connect anongit.gentoo.org:443 2>&1 </dev/null | sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/p'  | openssl x509 -noout -pubkey | openssl rsa -pubin -outform DER | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

openssl s_client -servername anongit.gentoo.org -connect anongit.gentoo.org:443 2>&1 </dev/null | sed -n '/BEGIN/,/END/p'  | openssl x509 -noout -pubkey | openssl rsa -pubin -outform DER | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Those commands return different certificate hashes (without and with using of SNI accordingly). And the second one is to be used with `git clone`.

Nevertheless, the actual reason to do such a thing still is a mystery for me.